# Replace string from category title

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I have these categories on my site : Movies, TV, Games. And I'd like to remove the 's' in the titles, cause it sounds strange with "Movies Stuff". Anyway, I tried with the code below but I don't understand why it wouldn't work? The 's' still stays.

```
      <title><?php echo str_replace("s","", single_cat_title()); ?>  Stuff - Mysite</title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<title><?php echo str_replace("s","", single_cat_title()); ?>  Stuff - Mysite</title>
```

Try this:

```
<title><?php echo str_replace("s","", single_cat_title("", false)); ?>  Stuff - Mysite</title>
```

I think you just need the false parameter at the end of single_cat_title, otherwise you are trying to display it before it gets echo'd. I'd also put the single_cat_title bit in a variable and use the variable in it's place within your echo.

Think you'd be better off using rtrim though, as you don't want to replace all 's' i'm guessing??

Comment: That worked! And I always wondered why people put those bits into a variable instead of just placing them inline. Looks cleaner to me that way. Are there any reference to that?

Comment: @Tony Fire - Glad to hear - codex is the best place to look: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title. I've had similar problems in the past which is why I remembered it! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo rtrim(single_cat_title('', false), 's'); ?>  Stuff - Mysite
```

That's the solution I'd come up with. It also will only remove the trailing `s` if there actually is one.

Function in PHP Docs: http://php.net/manual/de/function.rtrim.php

Answer (score 1):

try to use substr function in order to cut last character.
read more info [here](https://www.php.net/substr)

use this code

```
if (substr($title, 0, -1)=="s" || substr($title, 0, -1)=="S") {
    $title = substr($title, 0, strlen($title)-1);
}
echo $title;
```

Comment: That would cut down TV to T, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, your comment is correct. I edited my answer to provide you a code example

Answer (score 1):

I think you may run into other problems just trimming off the right "s", but this should work:

```
  <title><?php echo rtrim(single_cat_title(), "s"); ?>  Stuff - Mysite</title>
```